# How do i keep my DB and lucene in sync?

Tags: c#, lucene, lucene.net

So i can have a transaction in sql. But i am sure its not a good idea to wait in the middle of a transaction for lucene to finish also i am unsure if lucene is permanently saved in the DB until i do something there.

Whats the best way to keep my DB and lucene in sync? I am thinking of adding a lucene_queue in my sql db and everytime i make a change i add it into the queue (removing older queue if any) and delete it once it is done.

Is this the best way? Also i am unsure how to make lucene permanently keep the changes i made and how frequent i can/should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Use Solr's [DataImportHandler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler). It should work out of the box for you.

Comment: unfortunately i am using .net. Also i dont know how to use java nor have it available on the host machine. +1 though since it is a worthy answer.